# What does the interior of a Corellian Corvette’s bridge look like?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

In the *Star Wars* movies we've seen the inside of a bridge of capital ships like Star Destroyers or even Darth Vader’s *Executor* Star Destroyer.

[image: The bridge of Darth Vader’s the Super Star Destroyer “Executor.”]

I think we also see the bridge of some Rebel capital ships, such as whatever Admiral Ackbar is commanding during the attack on Death Star II (a Mon Calamari Cruiser)

[image: The bridge of Admiral Ackbar’s Mon Calamari Star Cruiser.]

But is there any scene from the bridge of a Corellian Corvette? If possible, the answer should be a screenshot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After picking up Yoda and Obi-Wan, Senator Bail Organa's Corellian corvette gets a message from Mas Amedda about an urgent Senate session.

And yes, this is the same CR-90 Corellian Corvette that would later end up being boarded by Darth Vader at the start of Episode IV.

> **Tantive IV** swept through the Kashyyyk system on silent running; this was still a combat zone. **Captain Antilles** wouldn’t even risk standard scans, because they could so easily be detected and backtraced by Separatist forces. (*Matthew Stovers ROTS novelization*)

[image]

And from other angles, thanks to masterful camera work following Obi-Wan and Yoda and Bail's conversation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the landing that shows it's CR-90, if novelization text wasn't enough

[image]

Comment: We also see the close-ups of the ship proving it's CR-90 later on, when Bail lands on Alderaan carrying Baby Leia.

Comment: Ironically, the novelization showed the scene on the screenshot differently - the Senator merely informed Yoda and co that he was summoned by Mas Amedda, they were NOT there to hear him in the cockpit. Instead, they were in the shuttle deck, preparing to attack Jedi Temple.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. My utter dislike of the prequels made me forget this scene.

Comment: @AndresF. - SOME pieces of prequels weren't so bad :)

Comment: Next up: I need a picture of the bridge of a Nebulon-B, that oft underappreciated vessel! (But I won't ask so similar a question, for fear of being downvoted for spamming ;) I'll leave the task to someone else).

Comment: @AndresF. - just ask in a week. That should help avoid downvotes. I think I might even have an answer

Comment: Isn't this the Tantive III, a CR70 Corvette, not the Tantive IV (CR90 class)? This one, shown in Episode 3, is much shorter than the one in Episode 4. Just compare them visually - http://www.nexusroute.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/tantive.jpg

Comment: Apparently, due to retconning this ship is no longer the _Tantive IV_ but the [_Sundered Heart_](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sundered_Heart). The bridge layout is different to that shown (briefly) at the end of Rogue One (comparison image [here](http://i.imgur.com/P2jtLO5.jpg)), which is most definitely the _Tantive IV_.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to DVK's excellent answer, there are actually some close up photos of the model blockade runner used in ANH.

[image: Bridge Closeup with posters]

This matches a photo from the *From Star Wars to Indiana Jones* source book I have, but I don't have access to it, just now. You can see the prop department stuck a miniature film poster and a pinup in there.

Answer (score 8):

This is from the book *Creating The Worlds of Star Wars: 365 Days*
which also confirms that it is in fact the same ship that Vader boards to capture Leia when you read the pages about the main hallway seen in *A New Hope*, as that exact set was recreated for *RotS*.

Very different from the final shot in *Rogue One* on the bridge of the *Tantive IV*! I wonder why this set from *RotS* wasn’t reused or rebuilt?
Gareth Edwards seemed to be very good about this type of stuff but I guess there are several canon versions of this cockpit now so it’s all good. I actually prefer the *Rogue One* version to be honest.

[image: Rear view of the cockpit with 4 chairs arranged in 2 pairs fore and aft, a long centre console with a large monitor, controls on the 2 sides and a blue screen forward through the windows]

[image: picture of page with the title "332: Alderaan Starcruiser Cockpit" and a description of the set. The top still from the movie shows the set with Kenobi, Organa and Yoda (and some crew) in the chairs with displays on the monitor and a planet in the windows; the still below shows the empty set pictured from the left side.]

Comment: Awesome! Nice find. Exactly what I was asking for :)

Answer (score 5):

Hi this is what I found on the internet from the interior of the Tantive IV

**episode 3:** (this is not the bridge)

[image]

**rogue one: the bridge of the Tantive IV**

[image]

[image]

a bridge from **another** rebel ship

[image]

**the tv show star wars rebels**: also not the bridge but a control room

[image]
bye,
And I hope I have helped someone with it.

Answer (score 3):

**There are at least four different CR-90 Corellian Corvettes featured so far in Season 2 of *Star Wars: Rebels* and a handful of scenes are set inside them.**

In Season 1's ["Droids in Distress"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Droids_in_Distress) we see inside Bail Organa's ship (which is so well-capped in DVK's answer) but all we see is a nondescript white hallway.

[image: Hallway]

In Season 2, when

> !the crew of the *Ghost* joins up with the Rebel Alliance,
>   the *Ghost* is often docked with one of the Rebel cell's three Corvettes, but a frustratingly few scenes take place inside the Corvettes.

[image: Docking]

In [*"The Lost Commanders"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Commanders) there is one scene in a previously unseen war room:

[image: WarRoom]

There are no windows to space, so **this is not the bridge.** A turn-around does show us some guys in [Rebel uniforms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112074/in-universe-answer-for-rebel-uniforms-in-star-wars-episode-iv-a-new-hope) working at the computer stations around the perimeter.

[image: Computer Dude]

Though we don't get to see inside a Corellian Corvette in the episode ["Wings of the Master"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wings_of_the_Master), we do get to see them actually *running a blockade* with the help of the *Ghost*, a fleet of A-Wings, and

> the first B-Wing.

Comment: +1 For effort and a well-researched answer, and also because I like *Star Wars: Rebels*.

Comment: This is a cool piece of research, but are any of those images **bridge** of the corvette? :)

Comment: @DVK No bridges yet... You answer the real question at hand, but I wanted to give Rebels a chance to deliver. I'll update with more images if they ever set another scene in the Corvette. This was mostly intended to give an example of other Rebels-era Corvette interiors, which are less pristine than Bail Organa's ship. There's probably an interesting future question about animation v. live action affecting ship design...

Comment: @DVK You are right, no bridges here. That's why I accepted your answer instead, which does deliver a great picture of an actual Blockade Runner bridge! But I think the effort in this answer also deserves an upvote :)

Comment: @AndresF. - sorry, i'll reserve the upvote till I see a bridge. No Jedi Mind Tricks are going to work on me